# .net Core 3.1 WebApi SSL connection fails but curl to the same service works

Tags: .net-core

I have a .net Core 3.1 API running on a redhat linux box.  The vendor my API talks to did an upgrade yesterday and since then we've been unable to connect to their service from the API itself.  Initially, our curl attempts to the URL were also failing, until they made some fixes to the SSL cert situation on their side.  Now, the curl works fine (no -k of course, just "curl -v %FullUrl%")
It returns the expected XML data from their service.

However, the API itself still fails the SSL connection with the same error it's gotten all along.  "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. - InnerException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."  I tried restarting the API service, then rebooting the entire linux box, to no avail.  I would love to be able to better log the steps of the SSL connection attempt, but I've been unable to google anything that seems to work for .net core, just a few .net framework versions that seem promising... If I could make them work for .net core!

Anything cert related seems to be eliminated because, as mentioned, the curl works just fine.  As well, the openssl s_client to their host works fine.  Running out of ideas, so here I am.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, is there any way to trust SSL cert just like in SQL connection without forcing anything? Have you tried PostMan to see if you can debug any more info?

Comment: Yes, I could simply bypass cert validation, but that opens up to MitM attacks.  PostMan calls work fine as well for whatever reason.  Just the API is failing the SSL connect.

Comment: Trusting cert is not a permanent solution. Just to see if everything else works. Do you have "useSSL": true somewhere in the settings? Also in Startup.cs do you have app.UseHttpsRedirection();? SSL is always tricky. See if domains match in the cert, cyphers, TLS version.

Answer (score 1):

The eventual answer here was actually quite shocking.  I put together a console app that logged many many bits of the SSL connection information, including many data points on every cert in the chain.  It turned out that .net Core was picking up a different cert than curl or openssl was.  The 2nd of 3 certs in the chain.  The cert had been "deactivated" via openssl, but because it wasn't deleted, .net Core still picked it up.  Everything I've seen says .net Core uses the same certs to connect as openssl does, but that is quite clearly a LIE!  :)

Comment: Curious to see the code you used to log this stuff. Having the same random issue only in dotnet core.

Comment: Sure thing, too long to post here, but hopefully this pastebin link works!  
https://pastebin.com/4pKXBMky

Let me know how it goes for you, it took longer than I care to admit to figure it out...  ;)